# Edit conditional formula for form field: @me condition not working in different accounts

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I have a strange behavior in my SharePoint application. I am using a SharePoint list form in which fields must only appear when the right user is logged in with his/her account. The formula works fine using @me term but unfortunately not for all users. It seems that in some cases the information behind @me cannot be used. Does someone know why for some Accounts it is working properly and for others not?

Update: I found the solution for the issue. It seems that in some cases the email addresses retrieved from @me function show for whatever reason capital letters for the first letters in first name and surname. Keeping that in mind in my conditional formula it works perfectly.This behavior occurs by the way also in person/group column showing work email addresses.

Thanks to all of you for your comments and support.

Comment: Are those external / guest users? Can you show us the expression you have used and on which type of field you have added this expression?

Comment: All users belong to the same company. The conditional formula is used for a single line text field. I used an expression which checks @me against a substring of string provided via lookup column: =@me==substring([$lookup],1,50).

Comment: All users are having access to source list from where lookup column is used? Also, what are the contents in the `[$lookup]` column, user email or user names? Can you add screenshots if possible?

Comment: yes users have access to source list. Content in the look up column is calculated column showing a string containing amongst others the email address of the required Person coming from single line text column. Screenshots unfortunately not possible yet.

Comment: I observed another strange aspect while checking the Account of one person for which it is not working. It seems that the "me" content cannot be retrieved. I did that via a trick: 1. Create single line text column called "Me", 2. Create calculated column and refer to "Me" column, 3. Delete "Me" column. In the Not working Account I retrieve "0". In my Account which works, I retrieve the desired Information. Perhaps this helps

Comment: Also, you are doing substring from 1 to 50. Are number of characters (50) same for all email addresses?

Comment: Actually I tested several scenarios. The simpliest example contained only one email address. More complex scenarios were with up to 12 email addresses each from single line text columns separated in the calculated column by distinct string markers. For the complex scenarios I used not only substring function but also indexOf function to determine right location of each email address substring. However, the problem that it works not for all users remains the same for all scenarios.

Comment: Do the affected user's have mailboxes? The @me resolves to a user's email address (NOT their login) and won't return a value for user's without a mailbox.

Comment: @theChrisKent, all users have email accounts they are working with in MS Outlook. The persons are also retrievable in a Person Or Group column.

Comment: @Jan, if issue is with the capital/lower case, you can adjust your formula using JSON operators. Try solutions given in my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is with the capital/lower case, you can use `toLowerCase()` operator (or `toUpperCase()`) in JSON formatting to convert it to same case.

**Example**:

```
=if(toLowerCase([$AssignedTo.email]) == toLowerCase(@me), 'true', 'false')
```

**Output**:

`Text` field showing when task is assigned to me:

[image]

`Text` field not showing when task is assigned to someone else:

[image]

You can adjust your formula using `toLowerCase()` operator according to your requirements.

**Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)